# Altair / vega-lite formatting a conditional text value

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I'm adding an automatic tooltip to an Altair chart successfully, but I'm unable to format the text as a currency.

Here's my code:

```py
contracts = {'date': ['2015-11-12','2020-11-11','2018-02-28','2021-02-27','2019-04-01','2021-03-31','2016-07-02','2019-11-01','2019-04-23','2019-10-14'],
        'type': ['Start date','End date','Start date','End date','Start date','End date','Start date','End date','Start date','End date',],
        'value': [2200000,2200000,250000,250000,127000,127000,35000,35000,148723,148723],
        'supplier': ['Capita','Capita','Deloitte','Deloitte','KPMG','KPMG','Herbert Smith','Herbert Smith','Spend Network','Spend Network'],
        'buyer': ['DWP','DWP','MOD','MOD','HMRC','HMRC','MOJ','MOJ','DFID','DFID']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(contracts, columns=['date','type','value','supplier','buyer'])

# Create a selection that chooses the nearest point & selects based on x-value
nearest = alt.selection(type='single', nearest=True, on='mouseover',
                        fields=['date'], empty='none')

chart = alt.Chart(df, title="Pipeline").mark_point().encode(
    alt.X(
        'date:T',
        scale=alt.Scale(zero=False),
        axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)
    ),
    alt.Y(
        'supplier:N',
        title="",
        sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field='yield', op='sum', order='descending'),
        scale=alt.Scale(rangeStep=20),
        axis=alt.Axis(grid=True)
    ),
    alt.Size('value:Q',
        scale=alt.Scale(range=[40, 400]),
        legend=alt.Legend(title='Contract size')
    ),
    color=alt.Color('buyer:N', legend=alt.Legend(title="Buyer")),

)

line = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('date:T', 
            ## xAxis title must be "Source: https://openopps.com"
            axis=alt.Axis(title="Source: https://openopps.com") 
           ),
    alt.Y('supplier:N',
             ## This is our units section, only describe the units of measurement here.
             axis=alt.Axis(title="Units: contract duration, contract value")
           ),
    color=alt.Color('buyer:N'),
    )

# Transparent selectors across the chart. This is what tells us
# the x-value of the cursor
selectors = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='date:T',
    opacity=alt.value(0),
    ).add_selection(
        nearest
    )

# Draw points on the line, and highlight based on selection
points = line.mark_point().encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(1), alt.value(0))
)

# Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
        text=(
            alt.condition(nearest, 'value:Q', alt.value(' '))
    )
)

# Draw a rule at the location of the selection
rules = alt.Chart(df).mark_rule(color='gray').encode(
    x='date:T',
).transform_filter(
    nearest
)

# Put the five layers into a chart and bind the data
alt.layer(
    chart, line, selectors, points, rules, text
)
```

This gives me this output

[image: contract chart]

You can see from the highlighted line that the tooltip (148723) is not formatted (e.g. no `$` for the currency).

I've tried doing a couple of things, without success...

This approach just trashes the chart formatting as whole, with the lines and legends and x-axis screwing up.

```py
# Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
        text=(
            alt.condition(nearest, 'value:Q', alt.value(' '), format='$.,3s')
    )
)
```

[image: error in chart rendering]

And this approach just fails on validation.

```py
# Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
        text=(
            alt.Text('value:Q', format='$.,3s'),
            alt.condition(nearest, 'value:Q', alt.value(' '))
    )
)
```

error message:

```
SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

        altair.vegalite.v3.api.Chart, validating 'required'

        'data' is a required property
```

I'm surprised that the first approach doesn't work, since the `alt.conditional` allows for `**kwargs`, but I guess I'm misunderstanding what I can pass to the conditional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format string `"$.,3s"` is not valid. Altair uses format strings from [d3 format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format), e.g. `"$.2f"`. You can specify it like this:

```
# ...
    text=alt.condition(nearest, 'value:Q', alt.value(' '), format='$.2f')
# ...
```